# jQuery: Rotate through <p>, hiding all but one. Then Repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this code to work mostly right. It hides all but one of the `<p>` tags of a certain class, then rotates to the next one on a click.  I want it to reset when it reaches the last `<p>` tag, and display the first one again, but it doesn't.  What am I doing wrong?

Here's the javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var curPoem=1;

if ($("h2.title").length==1) { break; }
else { $("h2.title").eq(0).after("\<sup\>\<small style='font-size: 10px; margin: 0 10px; float: right; position: relative; right: 50px; bottom: 30px;' \>Click the title to change the poem\<\/small\>\<\/sup>") }

$("p.lit").not($("p.lit:eq(0)")).hide();
$("p.lit").eq(0).show();
$("h2.title").not($("h2.title:eq(0)")).hide();

$("h2.title").eq(0).bind("click", function()
    {   $("p.lit").not($("p.lit:eq("+curPoem+")")).hide();
        $("p.lit").eq(curPoem).show();

        $("h2.title").eq(0).empty();
        for (i=0; i<$("h2.title").length-1; i++)
        {   $("h2.title").eq(0).append(litTitle[curPoem]);
        }
        document.title=litTitle[curPoem]+" by "+author;

        if (curPoem<$("h2.title").length)
        {   curPoem=(curPoem+1);
        }
        else if (curPoem==$("h2.title").length)
        {   curPoem=1;
        }
    });
});
```

The HTML It act's on:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var author="Bud Robert Berkich";
        var litTitle=["In the End", "Rental Car"];
    </script>

<div id="content">
        <h2 class="title">In the End</h2>
        <h3 class="author">Bud Robert Berkich</h3>
        <hr />
        <p class="lit">
            your other  for another for yourself    and not for me  selfish<br />
            <br />
            that other  indifferent not for you and now not for me too<br />
            <br />
            never   for me  but I never I othered   another selfless<br />
            <br />
            (I othered  the same    for you)<br />
            <br />
            and now nothing<br />
            <br />
            in the end  nothing<br />
        </p>
        <h2 class="title">Rental Car</h2>
        <p class="lit">
            4 AM.<br />
            <br />
            I find myself<br />
            in the vicinity<br />
            of the lake<br />
            that five years before<br />
            witnessed<br />
            "the fishing trip from hell."<br />
            <br />
            For me,<br />
            the beginning of the end.<br />
            <br />
            And I'm aware<br />
            of the fact<br />
            that if I'm<br />
            in the middle<br />
            of no front and back,<br />
            <br />
            I can easily<br />
            slip up a non-gated<br />
            park entrance<br />
            unawares.  But<br />
            <br />
            as the darkness<br />
            pushes in<br />
            and the insects<br />
            mock me<br />
            from behind trees<br />
            I can't see,<br />
            a feeling<br />
            <br />
            hell will be paid.<br />
            <br />
            I leave.
        </p>
        <hr />
        <p class="lit_bio">
            Bud Robert Berkich was born in Somerville, New Jersey and raised in Bound Brook, New Jersey.  He is a graduate of Bound Brook High School.  Bud holds an Associate of Arts in Humanities degree from Raritan Valley Community College and a Bachelor of Arts in Liberal Studies degree from Rider University.  He has been writing creatively since the age of eight.  He has had poetry published in The Idiom and a one-act play entitled End Streetpublished in The Rockhurst Review.  Bud is the co-founder and Director of the Somerset Poetry Group in Bridgewater, New Jersey.  He currently lives in Manville, New Jersey.
        </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: include some sample HTML please

Comment: Sample added, and the varibles it uses currently.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a complete example, but I grabbed your code and tried it and got this:

[image]

I replaced that "break" with a "return" and it corrected that error.

Also: I think your logic that modifies the `curPoem` index is a little off.  It starts at 1, goes to 2, and then stays there.   You need to rotate back to zero.  This is what I used:

```
if (curPoem<$("h2.title").length)
{
    curPoem++;
}
if (curPoem==$("h2.title").length)
{
    curPoem=0;
}
```

ps: you can use jsbin.com to upload and test and share Jquery-enabled html pages.

Here's a working example of your poems: http://jsbin.com/otamu5

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I actually got it to work yesterday. I couldn't before because my brain was fried.